# Google analytics not working for iOs

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I have used the sample app given by google analytics sdk and it works fine.But when I try to use it in my app,it does'nt work. I have created a seperate profile for my mobile app and got a new tracking id.It should be noted that there are no view controllers or appdelegate classes in my app as it is a a background app. Here is my code.

```
static NSString *const kTrackingId = @"UA-xxxxxx-x";//my new tracking id
static NSString *const kAllowTracking = @"allowTracking";
  NSDictionary *appDefaults = @{kAllowTracking: @(YES)};
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:appDefaults];
    // User must be able to opt out of tracking
    [GAI sharedInstance].optOut =
    ![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kAllowTracking];

    [GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 1;
    [GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
    self.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithName:@"CuteAnimals"
                                              trackingId:kTrackingId];

    NSMutableDictionary *event =
    [[GAIDictionaryBuilder createEventWithCategory:@"UI"
                                            action:@"buttonPress"
                                             label:@"dispatch"
                                             value:nil] build];
    [[GAI sharedInstance].defaultTracker send:event];
    [[GAI sharedInstance] dispatch];
```

Comment: it will affect after few hours in google analytics page.. so its better to check it tomorrow...

Comment: the changes took effect immediately for the sample app.

Comment: @Worker it generally takes times you can check it tomorrow as it does not +

Comment: @Worker, i already faced the same issue but the exact problem is that it takes times ...

Comment: Is there any restriction on in which class we can place this code? Like I said before I cant have view controllers or app delegate in my code.

Comment: i dont think that there is any restriction related to classes...

Comment: @Worker: There is no any restriction for placing code. Even its better to add code in app delegate or your share instance class so it will not initiate multiple time.